# JavaScript: The result of undefined++ is NaN, not undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, increment, var, hoisting

The 1st **console.log** output is 2. No doubt.
But why the 2nd console.log output is not undefined? Shouldn't output the undefined at first, then the variable b becomes NaN?

```
var a = 2;
console.log(a++);

var b;
console.log(b++);
```

Comment: Yes it's logical. Undefined + 1 is NaN

Comment: `x++` evaluates to `Number(<previous value of x>)`, not `<previous value of x>`, because it’s an operator on numbers. Logical enough, doesn’t really tend to come up, It Just Works That Way.

Answer (score 8):

Consider this:

```js
b = "foo"
c = b++
console.log(c)
```

Since the postfix `++` returns the value before incrementing, we expect `c` to be `foo`, however, it's `NaN`. Why is that?

This is by design, and described as follows in the standard (emphasis mine):

> [12.4.4.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
>
> UpdateExpression:LeftHandSideExpression++
>
> 1. Let lhs be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. **Let oldValue be ? ToNumber(? GetValue(lhs)).**
> 3. Let newValue be the result of adding the value 1 to oldValue, using the same rules as for the + operator (see 12.8.5).
> 4. Perform ? PutValue(lhs, newValue).
> 5. Return oldValue.

Translated to quasi-JavaScript, the above algorithm would be:

```
 function postIncrement(someVariable) {
     let oldValue = Number(someVariable.value); // Note "Number" here
     let newValue = oldValue + 1;
     someVariable.value = newValue;
     return oldValue;
 }
```

In other words, `value++` returns not just the value, but the value converted to a number. The conversion takes place before incrementing, and, since `Number("foo")` is `NaN`, this is what we get.

Yet another JavaScript quirk to take note of!

Comment: I reviewed your answer few times. Finally understood. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

You need to assign value to b or check for null condition before logging b.
b is NaN because its b++ is check for number.

Answer (score -3):

`var a = 2;`

Here you have declared a variable "a" with a value of "2", making its datatype "INTEGER".

```
console.log(a++);
```

The output is 2 and the variable "a" has a value of "3".

`var b;`

Here you have declared a variable "b" without any value, making its datatype "UNDEFINED".

`console.log(b++);`

The output is NaN because the variable "b" is null, and therefore increment operator cannot be applied.

Comment: `The output is NaN because the variable "b" doesnot have a default value` this sentence isn't correct. Please refer to @georg comment for more details.

Comment: @slesh this line is 100% correct, The output is NaN because the variable "b" doesnot have a default value, as b without any initial value has a value null, you cannot apply ++ to null value, hence it is Nan

Comment: You got *NaN* because you apply the arithmetic operation to *undefined*, but not because *b* doesn't have a default value.